# using property values versus session values, asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, session

I tryin gto get my head around doing something different, than I usually do.
Before I would set session values and reuse those values throught my website.
But I started to ask myself, can I use property values instead. Here's what I'm considering, and it appears to work great.

C#, 4.0

Instead of:

```
string strpersonid = userinfolist[0].ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("personid", strpersonid);
```

Or:

```
Session["sosuserid"] = "00001";
```

Why not use:
default.aspx-

```
private static string userid;
        public static string _UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return userid;
            }
            set
            {
                userid = value;
            }
        }

 _UserID = upUser.Name.ToString();
```

(from AD call)

and once the user submits the form, I have a class for my buslogic that reuses:

```
public class buslogic : _default

String userID = _UserID;
```

making it static keeps it thread safe, correct?

Thoughts, ideas? Thanx.

Update:
If it helps, the default.aspx page has the user submit to itself (default.aspx.cs, codebehind). That page is using the property values (making a call to the busLogic class, this I thought would be the issue) upon user form submit.

I also found this:
[To get public property values from the source page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: `making it static keeps it thread safe, correct?` Not in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 1):

Using `HttpContext.Session` or `HttpContext.Items` gives you a separate backing store for each request and thread.

This makes your code work correctly when run on multiple threads, and makes sure that each request gets its own value.

If you instead use a single `static` field, all requests will use the same field, and things will get very messed up.